# #1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 // when trying to INSERT in new data

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

I am new to SQL and using phpmyadmin for class. I am attempting to INSERT a new row into my table, to get my trigger audit log to show a change. However, every time I try to do the insert it is giving me the 1136 error. I have tried to rewrite it, deleted the employee table, and repopulated it with new employees. whenever I run the INSERT written below my error occurs. Any guidance on what is causing this error.

```
INSERT INTO `employee` (id, employee_fname, employee_lname, employee_gender)
VALUES (7, Jack, McQ, Male);
```

Below is my current table I am inserting into.

```
CREATE TABLE `employee` (
  `id` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `employee_fname` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `employee_lname` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `employee_gender` varchar(25) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;



INSERT INTO `employee` (`id`, `employee_fname`, `employee_lname`, `employee_gender`) VALUES
(1, 'Jane', 'Austin', 'Female'),
(2, 'Walt', 'Whitman', 'Male'),
(3, 'George', 'Martin', 'Male'),
(4, 'James', 'Brown', 'Male'),
(5, 'Mark', 'Sullivan', 'Male'),
(6, 'Mercedes', 'Lackey', 'Female');

--
-- Triggers `employee`
--
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `FOR INSERT` AFTER INSERT ON `employee` FOR EACH ROW INSERT INTO `emp_audit`
VALUES( 'The new ID=', NEW.id, NEW.employee_fname, NEW.employee_lname, NEW.employee_gender, 'was inserted on', NOW())
$$
DELIMITER ;


ALTER TABLE `employee`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
COMMIT;
```

ADDED per request

```
CREATE TABLE `emp_audit` (
  `id` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `auditdata` varchar(200) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;


ALTER TABLE `emp_audit`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
COMMIT;
```

Error

```
INSERT INTO `employee` (`id`, `employee_fname`, `employee_lname`, `employee_gender`) VALUES ('7', 'Jack', 'McQ', 'Male')
MySQL said: Documentation

#1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
```

Comment: You did not show `emp_audit` schema. I wonder if the problems is there...

Comment: Added, emp_audit

Answer (score 0):

I think your trigger should be as stated at the end.

But, beware, AFIK, in MySQL `FOR EACH ROW` is a misnomer, since it really does 'for all affected rows', demanding a loop in the trigger body.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `FOR INSERT` AFTER INSERT ON `employee` FOR EACH ROW
    INSERT INTO `emp_audit`(auditdata)
    VALUES(
        concat(
            'The new ID=', NEW.id, NEW.employee_fname, NEW.employee_lname, NEW.employee_gender, 'was inserted on', NOW()
        )
    )
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Thank you for the additonal concat and the (auditdata), I think that was my issue. stating the emp_audit without where the values would be stored was my issue 100%. concat I have seen used as it turns everything into a string preventing data type errors in the values correct?

Comment: @NathanBluhm, I wasn't sure about the data type errors... I devised a trial at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb/225260. From that, I understand you have to at least to `coalesce` your nullable columns.

Comment: @NathanBluhm, please, do not forget to upvote my solution :-)